# Perl function for slicing string with start, end and step

Tags: string, perl

I want to slice a string using start, end and step. Let's assume that start coordinate is 1, end coordinate is 22, step is 3. Slicing the string should select only elements that are in coordinates 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22. I have written a function get_subseq that does this. Is there a shorter way to do this in Perl?

```
sub get_subseq {
    my ( $seq, $start, $end, $step ) = @_;
    my $index = $start;
    while ( $index <= $end ) {
        print substr $seq, $index, 1;
        $index += $step;
    }
}

my $sequence = 'AGGGTAGAGTGAGAAGCACCAGCAGGCAGTAACAGC';

# The result should be GTAGACCC
get_subseq( $sequence, 1, 22, 3 );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way: generate the list of indices and then use `map` to fetch corresponding characters.

Rolled into one statement

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $seq = q(AGGGTAGAGTGAGAAGCACCAGCAGGCAGTAACAGC); 

my ($beg, $end, $step) = (1, 22, 3); 

my @subseq = 
    map { substr $seq, $_, 1 } 
    grep { ($_-$beg) % $step == 0 } 
    $beg..$end; 

say "@subseq";
```

This can be collapsed into one iteration over `$beg..$end` range

```
my @subseq = 
    map { ($_-$beg) % $step == 0 ? substr($seq, $_, 1) : () }
    $beg..$end;
```

If the result need be a string `join` the list by `''` (empty string).

And then there are of course libraries which can produce a range with stride. The [List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen) has such a `range` function, while it also has a whole range of interesting algorithms.

```
use List::Gen qw(range);

my @ss = map { substr $seq, $_, 1 } @{ range $beg, $end, $step };

say "@ss";
```

Its `range` returns really a generator, which comes with interesting properties. Dereferencing it produces the list of values. See documentation.

While these return the result in a single statement and are thus "shorter," I like your own sub in the question which is crystal clear and may be more efficient in many circumstances.

It can be simplified a bit more by the (rare) use of the C-style `for` loop

```
for (my $i = $beg; $i <= $end; $i += $step) { print substr $seq, $i, 1 }
```

---

Another way is to break your string into a list of its characters and then extract from that list the elements at needed positions

```
my @subseq = (split //, $seq)[ @indices ];
```

where you can use any method to obtain `@indices` (which need not be an array but can be a list generated right there, by any method used above for example).  Which of these two approaches is more efficient depends entirely on details -- length of the sequence, length of the index span to sample, their relation, the step size.

Answer (score 5):

No one likes using regexs?

```
join'',substr($seq,$start,$end-$start+1)=~/(?=(.)).{0,$step}/gs
```

This demonstrates using a regex match for this kind of thing, in a way that can sometimes be more efficient than loops or split and slice.  A more amusing, but not efficient, way would be to eschew the substr:

```
join '',$seq=~/(?<=.{$start})(?<!..{$end})(?=(.)).{0,$step}/gs
```

Comment: i do, and this one in particular :)

Comment: @zdim added an alternative for your amusement

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found by taking characters at position of interest.

> Step #1: generate array of indexes
>
> Step #2: split $seq into array
>
> Step #3: select characters at index position of $seq array
>
> Step #4: join result characters
>
> Step #5: output result

It is much faster than use of `substr` multiple times

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $seq = 'AGGGTAGAGTGAGAAGCACCAGCAGGCAGTAACAGC';
my($pos,$end,$inc) = (1,22,3);
my @index;

for(;$pos<=$end;$pos+=$inc) { push @index, $pos; }

say join('',(split('',$seq))[@index]);
```

Output

```
GTAGACCC
```